# How to get a URL from Beautiful Soup?

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am newbie at Python trying to write a crawling program; I want to crawl some data from BBC news using Beautiful Soup.

But when I inspected elements with Firebug, I found that the HTML in this page has no URL links.

```
<li class="">
<a class="navigation-wide-list__link navigation-arrow--open" data-panel-id="js-navigation-panel-World" href="/news/world">
    <span>World</span>
</a>
```

In `href = '/news/world'`, it's doesn't show the real URL links. What if I want to crawl all the links from this webpage? Is this because the website is using Javascript?

Answer (score 5):

You need to produce an *absolute URL* given the base/current url and the relative coming from the `href` value. A recommended way to do that is to use [`urlparse.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
from urlparse import urljoin  # on Python 3: from urllib.parse import urljoin

absolute_url = urljoin(url, href)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct/recommended answer. Learnt something new. Will delete my answer once I'm on a desktop. +1 :)

Comment: @JRodDynamite thanks, I think you should keep the answer since it solves the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last minor question:

There's nothing strange about the value of `href` being `/news/world`. That's a *relative reference*, and it's specified somewhere in the bowels of the [URI syntax RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2). Javascript is not required to handle them, they've been supported by browsers since time immemorial, to link to documents relative to either the current document, or relative to the host.

Comment: Just to make it clear: @alecxe's answer is the one that does what the OP wants to accomplish, and mine is meant to complement it by addressing the tangential questions in the post. For all I know, once his gets accepted, they could be merged into one.